# Use GetDate() as default parameter for SP in T-SQL not working

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, default-value

I am trying to create a SP in TSQL that gets month as parameter (in numeral format). I would like that if the parameter be suppressed by the user then the SP will use the current month.

I tried this but it says that I am using an incorrect syntax:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
    @month int = select Month(GetDate())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass func call as default parameter value:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
    @month int = select Month(GetDate())
```

should be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myproc
@month int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
 SET @month = COALESCE(@month, Month(GetDate()));

 SELECT @month;
END;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e9b20ce416851dfc47a99b1981c5fcf6)**

If user does not provide value for `@month` then by default it is `NULL` and `COALESCE` will set proper value.